# Dynamically shrink div when resolution gets smaller | Viewport or overflow issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I'm facing the problem of building a responsive website.

Main part of the site is a  with a fixed width of 62em. Now I want this div to shrink as a whole if the resolution gets smaller, with no scrollbars shown and no zoom used.
Currently when I open the site in a smaller resolution, scrollbars are shown but I do not have the opportunity to zoom out

Curently I'm using a flexbox design and Chrome as debug tool. What I'm really wondering about is, that sometimes the  seems to work the way I want in Chrome's dev mode and sometimes it does not. I have really no idea why this behaves so randomly.

I'm interessted in a solution using only CSS.

Does anyone have a tip?

My viewport is set to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Could a overflow issue may cause this problem?

Comment: You either need to set the width in vw or % to make it responsive to the screen size, or use a media query for resolutions you want to support.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to work with % values to max-width so it never grows bigger than your viewport size. Flexbox can have some weird behaviours sometimes. If you share some of your code I'll maybe be able to help you a little better.